# QueueScheduler not firing when interval is set

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

This code doesn't print anything:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
 QueueScheduler.main.schedule(after: Date() + 1.seconds, 
                              interval: .seconds(1)){
                                print("test Output")}
 return true
}
```

but if I do it without `interval:` it prints one time as expected. Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The variation without `interval` is using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/85ee0406ac173a4be7719d6228d6f7a0ab357e5e/Sources/Scheduler.swift#L275) and checking for disposal before executing the action. So the action will run unless you explicitly call `dispose` on the returned `Disposable`.

But [the variation with `interval` is using `DispatchSource.makeTimerSource` and then capturing the returned `DispatchSourceTimer` in the resulting `AnyDisposable` action](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/85ee0406ac173a4be7719d6228d6f7a0ab357e5e/Sources/Scheduler.swift#L343). Since `DispatchSourceTimer` cancels itself when it is released, you must store the returned `Disposable` or else it `deinits` and the timer is cancelled.

I don't know if this is intentional behavior or a bug. On the one hand it's a bit confusing that such similarly named methods act differently in this regard. But on the other hand, the one that repeats on an interval is *much* easier to leak if you forget to handle the `Disposable` it returns, so perhaps it makes sense.

#### Update:

This is a bug and is [fixed in 3.1.0](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#310).